# What circuit should I use to measure current around 500mA?

Tags: current-measurement

What circuit should I use to measure (alternating) current around 500mA AC? I am working on smart energy meter project. I read about the [Melexis 91206 Hall-effect current sensor](https://www.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx91206-datasheet-melexis.pdf) but didn't understand how to use it in a circuit.

Comment: Add a datasheet, schematic, and so on. Also, I'm not sure but Melexis parts are gennerally not available for the low-quantity user - they are almost solely automotive and talk about MoQ of hundreds of thousands of parts.

Comment: http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/technologies/semiconductors/analog/sensors/current/Pages/7027175-MLX91206LDC-CAH-003-TU.aspx?IM=0  in stock with datasheet  $2.59 (1)

Comment: What type of current are you sensing - AC or DC? What is the range of current?

Comment: See page 18 of the datasheet. It appears you have to put the IC inside a coil, through which the current you want to measure will pass. Doesn't seem the easiest thing to do in my opinion... May I suggest you look into the Allegro MicroSystems Hall sensors? I have used them already and are easier than this Melexis sensor (or seem to be).

Comment: I have purchased a Allegro Microsystem hall sensor(ACS722 IC) but i don't know how to use it.This is a very small IC.can you please help me in solving this problem.This is a 8pin 5amp IC.

Answer (score 1):

INA219 is the low current sensor which can measure the low current like in milli amperes. you can follow the following tutorial for complete detail .

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ina219-current-sensor-breakout.pdf

for AC current measurement you can use ACS712( the exact part number is ACS712ELCTR-05B-T). This sensor is used for AC current measurement

Comment: this sensor can be used for the measurement of DC current.I want to measure AC current.

Comment: "*I want to measure AC current.*" Then put that in your question - not in the comments - and specify if it is 500 mA RMS, peak to peak, etc., and the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The most common technique involves the use of a current transducer such as a shunt resistor, a current transformer, or a hall effect device that converts current to voltage or pulses.

The output of the current transducer is then monitored by a microprocessor that samples and records the signal on a regular basis. The rate of sampling is determined by the expected rate of load change and the desired accuracy of the final data. Sampling several times a second is not unusual.

From the samples collected, it is then possible to compute average, peak, hourly, weekly, monthly etc. reports for energy or power. This data can be communicated over a serial link or locally displayed.